# Change the data and time format

Tags: javascript, date

I am using `owl-date-time` to get the date and time in angular.

It returns the data and time format as: `2018-08-20T07:37:09.000Z`

Is there a way that I can modify the format as: `2018-08-20 09:37`

Any help is apprecitated.

Comment: what about this? https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_date.asp

Comment: maybe its help u https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/#locale-formats

Answer (score 0):

There is a *momentjs* integration:

```
npm install ng-pick-datetime-moment moment --save
```

Having done that, you can use moment format strings in `OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS`. An example [from the docs](https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/#locale-formats):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS} from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import { OwlMomentDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime-moment';

// See the Moment.js docs for the meaning of these formats:
// https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/
export const MY_MOMENT_FORMATS = {
    parseInput: 'l LT',
    fullPickerInput: 'l LT',
    datePickerInput: 'l',
    timePickerInput: 'LT',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [OwlDateTimeModule, OwlMomentDateTimeModule],
    providers: [
        {provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS, useValue: MY_MOMENT_FORMATS},
    ],
})
export class AppExampleModule {
}
```

The format you are looking for is `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'`:

```js
console.log(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit overkill but you can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) like this:

```js
console.log(new moment(`2018-08-20T07:37:09.000Z`).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

**However**, if you want your output string to be exactly alike do something like this:

```js
let input = '2018-08-20T07:37:09.000Z';

let date = new moment(input).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

let time = (a => `${a[2]}:${a[1]}`)(input.split('T')[1].split(':').map(s => s.slice(0,2)));

console.log(`${date} ${time}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: The format should be `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'` (assuming the OP wants 24 hour time), which makes redundant the second part of your answer.

Comment: The question is specifically about `owl-date-time` not about general time string formatting.

Comment: @FK82 IMHO, question states that op is getting that format from `owl-date-time` and wan't to further display/process it as the mentioned format

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, moment.js is an overkill.For just formatting purpose, you could use plain javascript.

```js
time = new Date('2018-08-20T07:37:09.000Z').toLocaleString().split(',')[1];
console.log(time)
time = time.split('').splice(0,6).join('');
date  ='2018-08-20T07:37:09.000Z'.split('T')[0];
console.log(date + time)
```

Comment: Note that *toLocaleString* is implementation dependent and will frequently (but not always) reflect system settings, so splitting and splicing will not produce consistent results on different platforms.

Comment: The date object reflects the system settings, so i guess using toLocaleString with options and locale should produce consistent results.

Comment: It doesn't, because while the options themselves are standardised, what they produce is not, that too is implementation dependent. E.g. in some hosts, specifying a particular language overrides`hour12 : false`, making it impossible to get 24 hour time whereas in others it doesn't. :-(

Comment: Yeah minor changes might appear when using different platforms but as I have noticed it, the string itself is the same. Mac adds the timezone while ubuntu doesn't. But the split splice works on both. What's the right way to go about this?

Comment: There are already many questions and answers on the same topic, the difference here is the use of Angular's *owl-date-time* (which probably should have been added as a tag). I would use Date methods and manual formatting or a library.